# How can I show another image on hover?

Tags: css, image

Im trying to overlay another image over an image whenever someone toggles the hover state.

How can I show the second image?

```
<a href="#"> <img src="my-image-url" /> </a>
```

Comment: I don't get it, what do you want to get?

Comment: Your HTML here has nothing to do with the HTML in your fiddle.

Comment: If you have a code for that, why are you posting question here? :/ And also, you are not even showing use what image you want to work on.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan It's like most encouraging example why not to answer to users under 300 rep :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pDeKy/1/

### HTML

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100" class="hovery" />
</a>
```

### CSS

```
a {
    position: relative;
}
/* Make our images sit on top of one and other  */
 a img {
    position: absolute;
}
.hovery {
    display: none;
}
a:hover .hovery {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Downvote because? Have I mis-interpreted the requirements? Can somebody care to explain what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, Image shows up when you hover the div:

Example : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/nXdMn/5/)

HTML:

```
<div><a href="#"> <img src="http://img122.imageshack.us/img122/1512/spiderman4teaserwo2.jpg" /> </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div:hover img{
   opacity: 1;
}
img{
 position: relative;
    width :100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```